# Running multiple NodeJS JavaScript Files at the same time, issues when more than one file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to run multiple JavaScript files with Node when `node group-shout-start.js` is run. This would run all the JavaScript files in the folder, which does work however when there's more than one file it starts throwing errors.

The code that runs all of the JavaScript files is,

```js
const scriptsFolder = './webhooks/member-counters/'

const files = fs.readdirSync(scriptsFolder);
const funcs = files.map(function(file) {
  return exec.bind(null, `node ${scriptsFolder}${files}`)
})
```

Again, it works fine. However, when there's more than one JavaScript file it gives me this error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\gavin\OneDrive\Desktop\webhooks.eastsideapp.com\webhooks\member-counters\460188583043530762.js,eastside_official_server.js'
```

I'm quite new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You made a typo in your `map` callback. You're appending the `files` array instead of the `file` string from the callback argument.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change from `${files}` to `${file}`.  You just want the one file that `.map()` is currently iterating for that specific iteration, not the whole array:

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(scriptsFolder);
const funcs = files.map(function(file) {
  return exec.bind(null, `node ${scriptsFolder}${file}`);
});
```